# Applying a frequency and phase sensitivity post-recording

Tags: matlab, non-linear

I have a particle velocity sensor that I'm recording, which has a non-linear frequency and phase response. I have frequency and phase correction curves for it, however, the proprietary acquisition software I'm using can only apply single value sensitivities on channels.

Is it possible I could apply the frequency and phase response to the signal in MATLAB after it has been recorded?

[image: Frequency and phase responses]

Comment: not being from the field you're working in (whcih is that?), I have no idea what a particle velocity sensor is. And what the axes tell me – is that movement harmonic, so that velocity has a frequency? Or is the frequency descriptive of the particle or something else, but not the velocity?